# PyGradle fails on initial build

Tags: python, gradle, pygradle

Hurrah, there's actually a PyGradle tag.

Linux Mint 18.3 OS, basically Ubuntu Xenial.

I love this idea. Gradle is the best, and so is Python. I just followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/tree/master/examples/example-project). Incidentally I specified v 5.4 for the Gradle wrapper.

I ran:

```
$ ./gradlew build
```

... and I got:

```
...

> Task :installProject FAILED
Install PyLookup2019-09 ............................................. [STARTING]
Obtaining file:///home/mike/software%20projects/eclipse-workspace/PyLookup2019-09
No files/directories in /home/mike/software projects/eclipse-workspace/PyLookup2019-09 (from PKG-INFO)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

There are files, some of which .py files, and directories in the project directory containing more .py files. Anyone got an idea what might be wrong?

In particular, if the PyGradle people (from LinkedIn I believe) see this, could you explain what the phrase "(from PKG-INFO)" means in this error message?

Also, at the GitHub page it says "create a standard python project", and a file structure is shown. But I'm not sure where this "standard project" is coming from, or what should be in setup.cfg, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this example which I see is complete https://github.com/linkedin/pygradle/tree/master/examples/iris-classification

One possible cause for this failed build will be wrongly configured repository in build.gradle or misconfigured setup.py
Please check them both

If you're using python-web-api plugin from PyGradle use this following example:
https://github.com/blankdots/pygradle-falcon-api